# unable to install mongodb on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mongodb

I performed the first two steps of importing the public key, by:

```
prachi@prachi-3000-N100:~$  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
[sudo] password for prachi: 
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.z5S9qmVca3 --trustdb-name /etc/apt//trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 7F0CEB10: "Richard Kreuter <richard@10gen.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

then the second step was to list file for mongo;

```
prachi@prachi-3000-N100:~$ echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
```

then during the third step,i.e,while reloading the repository, its showing this error:

```
prachi@prachi-3000-N100:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

what is wrong?? Please help

Answer (score 3):

You have a lock from another apt-get process that may be running or has died.

To check if anything is running

```
ps aux | grep apt
```

If nothing is running remove the locks that might be there

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```